# cannot connect to the nexus server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

when I try and connect to the nexus server it says java.net.connectionexception:connection refused:no further information. does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Could you try to give us some more information? There's not much to go on here. What version of Minecraft are you running, for example?

Comment: Which Nexus server are you referring to? If it's PhoenixNexus, they're currently blacklisted by Mojang.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways this issue could have arisen.

- If your network or computer has any proxies or firewalls, you may want to remove them. If your can't then try using someone else's wifi.
- If you're using cracked/hacked Minecraft, it just won't work.
- If someone else has been banned on your IP, it often says that for awhile (until you are banned too.)
- Your local servers may be down. Wait awhile.
- The nexus servers may be down. Wait awhile.
- Re-install Minecraft (do this last)
- Make sure you're running without mods/shaders/hacks.
- Make sure you're in the right version.

Comment: I would highly suggest you take a look at the [Markdown Formatting Guide](http://commonmark.org/help/). It will give valuable insights as to how to format your posts correctly, as StackExchange uses Markdown primarily.

Comment: I write all my posts within those constrains, but this post is the first one from a mobile device, and I am still getting used to the system. @KazWolfe

Comment: Still, use `- ` instead of the actual bulletpoint character, please. That should work from mobile.

Comment: Actually, looking through your post history, there have been quite a few posts corrected for the same things. I would *highly* recommend going back and seeing what edits have been made to your posts. Specifically, please try to avoid the use of `<html>` markup unless absolutely necessary. Markdown is your friend here.